# How do I strip out in PHP everything but printing characters?

Tags: php, regex

I am working with this daily data feed. To my surprise, one the fields didn't look right after it was in MySQL. (I have no control over who provides the feed.)

So I did a mysqldump and discovered the zip code and the city for this record contained a non-printing char. It displayed it in 'vi' as this:
<200e>

I'm working in PHP and I parse this data and put it into the MySQL database. I have used the trim function on this, but that doesn't get rid of it. The problem is, if you do a query on a zipcode in the MySQL database, it doesn't find the record with the non-printing character.

I'd like the clean this up before it's put into the MySQL database.

What can I do in PHP? At first I thought regular expression to only allow a-z,A-Z, and 0-9, but that's not good for addresses. Addresses use periods, commas, hyphens and perhaps other things I'm not thinking of at the moment.

What's the best approach? I don't know what it's called to define it exactly other than printing characters should only be allowed. Is there another PHP function like trim that does this job? Or regular expression? If so, I'd like an example. Thanks!

I have looked into using the PHP function, and saw this posted at PHP.NET:

```
<?php
$a = "\tcafé\n";
//This will remove the tab and the line break
echo filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
//This will remove the é.
echo filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
?>
```

While using FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH does indeed strip out the <200e> I mentioned seen in 'vi', I'm concerned that it would strip out the letter's accent in a name such as André.

Maybe a regular expression is the solution?

Comment: The 1st idea that came to me is a regular expression. Maybe: $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\.\,\-\s]/i', '', $str); Put other good characters inside the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the posting. How could this be adapted to include accents over letters too? (See the edit I did above).

Comment: Added an answer for you with regexp and special characters in German and French.

Comment: It's weird. I've added the 0x200E character in the string and it is stipped when I use `var_dump(filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW));`.

Comment: It may filter out some characters, but not the <200e> which appeared in 'vi'. When I added the FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH option, it did indeed filter out the <200e> but it also filtered out é. I ended up going with user4035's answer, since it did filter out <200e> but it left é alone.

Comment: In 'vi' the example I have for testing this looks like this on the screen: This<200e>that. Here is the 'od' dump of it: 0000000 064124 071551 100342 072216 060550 005164, 'od -x' is: 0000000 6854 7369 80e2 748e 6168 0a74, and the 'od -a' is: 0000000   T   h   i   s   b nul  so   t   h   a   t  nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
<?php
$string = "\tabcde éç ÉäÄéöÖüÜß.,!-\n";
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\!\.\, \-éâëïüÿçêîôûéäöüß]/iu', '', $string);
print "[$string]";
```

It gave:

```
[abcde éç ÉäÄéöÖüÜß.,!-]
```

Add all the special characters, you need into the regexp.

Comment: This worked out on my example perfectly and preserved the accented letters. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP filters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

I would recommend on using the `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` filter, or anything that fits what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the posting, please see my comments in the edit I did above regarding accented letters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use this little regex replace:

```
preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]+/', '', $your_value);
```

It basically strip out all non-printing characters from $your_value

Answer (score 0):

If you work in English and do not need to support unicode characters, then allow just `[\x20-\x7E]`

...and remove all others:

```
$s = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]+/', '', $s);
```